# Change Scene In SpriteKit with Button (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scene

I have a main menu set up with a play button (thats all) and i want to press the play button and then be taken to a new scene where the game plays

the question is how do you change the Scene in sprite kit using a button?

I have looked everywhere but i am just beginning with swift

Answer (score 1):

A UIButton participates in the [Target-Action design pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) in iOS.  After you create your button you need to decide which object will be told when the button is pressed (that's the "target") and you need to decide what method on that object will be called in response to the button press (the "action").

The "target" object will implement the logic to start the game in the "action" method you define for it.